# Rigid Body Constraints Rapidly Twitch

Tags: physics, constraints, rigid-body-simulation

So I'm trying to make a simple car with rigid body constraints, but when the wheels spin they rapidly twitch around. Any help? Everything else works but I can't figure out this.[image]